# Clear the .NET-downloaded application cache without Mage?

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

I have a .NET application that I distribute using ClickOnce and I make available online only. How do I clear the download cache from a users' machine that doesn't have Visual Studio installed?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Visual Studio isn't needed, just [Mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It comes with the Windows SDK for people that haven't gotten it via Visual Studio or the Framework SDK.

Another option would be to [write code](http://bombayboy.wordpress.com/2006/07/03/) to clear the cache.  Or you could have them delete the folder ClickOnce files are installed in (`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Apps` on my Windows 7 machine). That would be a last resort since it will remove every ClickOnce application they have installed.

You don't have to have Mage installed to clear the cache; running `rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache` from the command line accomplishes the same thing as `mage -cc`.

Comment: Thanks! Someone left a comment to the link you provided and left this gem: "Another option: Run this from the command-line:
rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache" Exactly what I needed.

Comment: dfshim is [part of ClickOnce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714192/issue-with-registry-key-of-dfshim-dll), and ClickOnce is [part of the .Net framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce), for anyone else who is wondering.