# Clickonce Online Only Uninstall

Tags: clickonce, filesystems, uninstallation

Is there an established way to uninstall an application that was deployed via ClickOnce using the Online Only method? I found it's location buried deep in the %APPDATA% tree, but I want to make sure I back it out all the way without creating future problems when I reinstall it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just dealing with your machine and it's the only ClickOnce application installed, delete everything under the Apps folder (`C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Apps` on my machine).

You can also use a command line tool that comes with the Windows and .NET Framework SDKs.  It's called [Mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(VS.80).aspx).  Running `mage -cc` will clear all the ClickOnce apps off your machine.

If you don't have mage, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418542).

Just know that all of these methods remove *all* ClickOnce applications.  I don't know of a good way to remove a single, online-only application without affecting other ClickOnce apps.

Comment: Turns out this works too: rundll32 %windir%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache

Comment: yep, pretty much the `mage -cc` equivalent.