# How to completely wipe a previous ClickOnce installation?

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have a curious problem:
My app is distributed through ClickOnce. I recently installed three new clients on a new location. They worked. After an update however, all old clients worked fine, but the three new clients did not. As my code is swallowing an exception somewhere I have been unable thusfar to pinpoint where the error lies.

When I XCopy the latest version of the app to the desktop of the three new client computers the program works fine. So, I thought uninstalling and reinstalling the program from the download location should fix the problem, but it does not!

I can think of two explanations:

- The new location has some firewall/virusscanner in place that doesn't like the latest version of my app when it is run from a standard ClickOnce directory, but it allows execution from the desktop.
- Some old settings (the app uses user scoped and app scoped settings) remain in effect after the uninstall. When I find and check the user.config file for the app however, I find no incorrect setttings there.

  Thusfar, I have been unable to reproduce the error on any other machine.

How can I solve this!?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on "work" versus "not work."  What is not working?  What do you observe when you use the new version from a deployment that "does not work"?

Comment: At the moment not. I cannot debug the program on the new location and I have been unable to reproduce the error on my development computer (or any other for that matter). My hunch is that some old .dll or .config file is still being used and I'd like to know how to found out about that and how to remedy that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate question. There is a method to clear the download cache *without* having to resort to using Mage.exe.

Look [here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418542/clear-the-net-downloaded-application-cache-without-mage-exe)

Answer (score 1):

You need the mage.exe console application for this:

> Mage.exe -cc

-cc stands for ClearCache.