# The deployment identity at the deployment provider is not the same as the original deployment identity

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i have an application that is causing me alot of trouble. the guy who created it doesnt work at our company anymore and it is up to me to fix and release the program for our windows 7 machines

However i get the following stacktrace:

```
    PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18063
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18063 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file://nkm18427/PRV-JSKR/Backup/DOPeSolutions.application
    Deployment Provider url     : http://nkm18f53:8181/DRIFT/DOPe%20Data%20Management/DOPeSolutions.application
                        Server      : Apache-Coyote/1.1

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of \\nkm18427\PRV-JSKR\Backup\DOPeSolutions.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The deployment identity at the deployment provider is not the same as the original deployment identity.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [05-03-2014 13:45:05] : Activation of \\nkm18427\PRV-JSKR\Backup\DOPeSolutions.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [05-03-2014 13:45:05] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SubscriptionSemanticValidation)
        - The deployment identity at the deployment provider is not the same as the original deployment identity.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.FollowDeploymentProviderUri(SubscriptionStore subStore, AssemblyManifest& deployment, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how i can fix it?

Comment: how did you solve it???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem

I usually get this error whenever I tried to publish a click once app with a different target architecture then what is currently installed on a machine (x86 vs x64)

OR

When the signature/certificate of the application is different than the original publish

### Solution

I would try making sure that your target architecture has not been changed (if you published it originally as x32, make sure the version you are trying to install is still x32)

or

make sure that nothing has changed with the signature settings (if you published originally with a certificate, make sure it is still the same certificate)

If you made these changes on purpose however, all you'll need to do on the host machine is uninstall the existing application on the machine, and re-install with the version you are trying to install, that should resolve the error and allow you to install the new version.

Comment: I've generated a new test cerficate after the previous one expired. Now I have this error when I try to install it. What can I do??

Answer (score 5):

You will get the same exception when you changed the "Publish Location" -> "Installation Folder URL (if different than above)", but forgot to change the following: "Install Mode and Settings" -> "Updates..." -> "Update location (if different than publish location)".

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this error message in the following situation.  I updated my ClickOnce application to sign the ClickOnce manifests with a trusted certificate issued by my organization.  This particular application was using a self-signed certificate in the previous version.  This in turn changes the publisherIdentity element (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd996956.aspx) and it's generated hash in the [ClickOnce Deployment Manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k26e96zf.aspx) (.application file).

In your situation, it's possible that the previous developer re-signed the application with a different certificate than the previous version.  Or perhaps the application had not been signed in the previous version.  Judging by the error message you are seeing, this is almost certainly an application that has been published as a ClickOnce application.

Assuming that you have your hands on the code, and that you are using Visual Studio, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and select Properties.  Then click on Signing to see signing details such as whether or not the manifests are signed, and if so, which certificate was used.

Comment: I've generated a new test cerficate after the previous one expired. Now I have this error when I try to install it. What can I do??

Answer (score 1):

I received this exception because I had downloaded the .application file using an IP address instead of the full DNS name. The application was being hosted on a CDN, so certainly would not be a typical situation but in my case switching to the full name fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting this error while trying to install it from a different internet URL than specified in the project properties.

Answer (score 1):

When testing several different ClickOnce updates in a short time, I noticed that I got this error (*"Application cannot be started"* with details *"The deployment identity at the deployment provider is not the same as the original deployment identity."*), even when I uninstalled all previously installed packages!

Clearing the ClickOnce cache (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419898/10928234)) and rebooting didn't solve the problem.

But after I **cleared the browser cache** (Chrome in my case), I was able to install the ClickOnce package. So before you test installing an update (as a developer, by visiting the Installation URL), make sure you clear the (default) browser cache first.

For Chrome: [once](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) or [disable cache during session](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache)

For Edge: [once](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/view-and-delete-browser-history-in-microsoft-edge-00cf7943-a9e1-975a-a33d-ac10ce454ca4)